# LTR to RTL Conversion

Tags: css, angular, sass

I have developed an application in angular and is completed which includes approx. 80 modules. Now I need to convert the language to arabic which is RTL. I used SCSS as a CSS library. Is there any easy way to convert my LTR application to RTL because many styles are affecting while using direction=rtl;

I don't want to convert every .scss files in the module.

Comment: what is your exact question?
but wouldn't a global scss or an adjustment in the angular.json (stylePreprocessorOptions) help?

Comment: Actually I have to toggle the values applied to margin-left and margin-right in global css and the same for border, padding, float, etc.

Answer (score 3):

I'm using [css logical properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Logical_Properties) which should be supported in most of the browsers.

Instead of using `margin-left` you write `margin-inline-start`.

The cool part is that if you are using `postcss` with [`postcss-preset-env`](https://preset-env.cssdb.org/) you just can use the new syntax, it will convert it to css that supports by all the browsers based on the `dir` attribute.

For example:

```css
// some.css
.my-class {
  float: inline-start;
  margin-inline-start: 10px;
}
```

it will produce

```css
// some.output.css
[dir="ltr"] .my-class {
  float: left
}
[dir="rtl"] .my-class {
  float: right
}
[dir="ltr"] .my-class {
  margin-left: 10px 
}
[dir="rtl"] .my-class {
  margin-right: 10px
}
```

With this output css you can just set the `dir` attribute of you `html` element to
`rtl`, and the browser will use the proper styles.

I'm using this approach in a large code base, it works like a charm.

Another approach is to use [rtl-css,](https://github.com/MohammadYounes/rtlcss) which is a tool that creates new css files with flipped directions.
It has several webpack plugins as well, such as [rtlcss-webpack-plugin](https://github.com/wix/rtlcss-webpack-plugin)

Comment: Thank you for the response. but I don't want to alter the existing css. because I have alternate approach if I want to do the same by altering the existing code. I don't know whether it is possible or not to switch the values in left margin or padding to right one and vise versa

Answer (score 0):

I have written a [crud python tool](https://gist.github.com/nyurik/d438cb56a9059a0660ce4176ef94576f) that can mass-convert all CSS and SCSS files from physical to logical in one go.  To use, save that file somewhere, e.g. `to-logical.py`. Requires python3.  Can be used on a single file or whole dirs, and even recursive.  Can handle scss expressions. The tool currently handles `left, right, top, bottom, margin-*, border-*, padding-*, min-width, max-width, min-height, max-height, text-align`.

```
python3 to-logical.py -r <path-to-dir>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since I am using SCSS it becomes easy by adding mixins. Below are the mixins for common rtl to ltr properties and I replaced all the border, margin, padding, position and border-radius to generate from this mixins, and it worked fine. Took some long process but perfect.

```
@mixin rtl-value($property, $ltr-value, $rtl-value, $imp:null) {
  #{$property}: $ltr-value;

  :host-context([dir=rtl]) & {
    #{$property}: $rtl-value;
  }
}


@mixin border-radius-gen($tl, $tr, $br, $bl, $imp:null) {
  @include rtl-value(border-top-left-radius, $tl, $tr, $imp);
  @include rtl-value(border-top-right-radius, $tr, $tl, $imp);
  @include rtl-value(border-bottom-right-radius, $br, $bl, $imp);
  @include rtl-value(border-bottom-left-radius, $bl, $br, $imp);
}

@mixin margin-gen($top:null, $right:null, $bottom:null, $left:null, $imp:null) {
  margin-top: $top $imp;
  @include rtl-value(margin-right, $right, $left, $imp);
  margin-bottom: $bottom $imp;
  @include rtl-value(margin-left, $left, $right, $imp);
}

@mixin padding-gen($top:null, $right:null, $bottom:null, $left:null, $imp:null) {
  padding-top: $top $imp;
  @include rtl-value(padding-right, $right, $left, $imp);
  padding-bottom: $bottom $imp;
  @include rtl-value(padding-left, $left, $right, $imp);
}

@mixin border-gen($top:null, $right:null, $bottom:null, $left:null, $imp:null) {
  border-top: $top $imp;
  @include rtl-value(border-right, $right, $left, $imp);
  border-bottom: $bottom $imp;
  @include rtl-value(border-left, $left, $right, $imp);
}

@mixin position-gen($top:null, $right:unset, $bottom:null, $left:unset, $imp:null) {
  top: $top $imp;
  @include rtl-value(right, $right, $left, $imp);
  bottom: $bottom $imp;
  @include rtl-value(left, $left, $right, $imp);
}
```

Examples

```
.style{
  @include margin-gen($left: 1px, $right: 1px, $top: 1px, $bottom: 1px, $imp: !important)
  @include padding-gen($left: 1px, $right: 1px, $top: 1px, $bottom: 1px, $imp: !important)
  @include border-gen($left: 1px solid #ccc, $right: 1px solid #ccc, $top: 1px solid #ccc, $bottom: 1px solid #ccc, $imp: !important)
}
```